# htaccess reg exp with params

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this url with optional params at the end :

```
http://domain.local/?_escaped_fragment_=watch/1/10/test/optionalparams/optionalparams/optionalparams/optionalparams..
```

and i want to redirect it to

```
http://domain.local/videos/watch/test?id=10
```

I tried a lot of htaccess rewrite rules and conds but it's not working at all..
This is my htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)(/(.*)?)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /videos/%1/%4?id=%3 [NC,R=301]
```

Can someone help me to find the solution.. :)

Thanks in advance !

---

**Edit more precisions :**

When i try this url :

```
?_escaped_fragment_=watch/1/10/title
```

with this rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /videos/%1/%4?id=%3 [NC,R=301]
```

It's working like i want ! 
But if i try an url with anything after /title like this

```
?_escaped_fragment_=watch/1/10/title/param/param/param
```

It's not working...
I've tried with this reg ex with a different cond

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)(/(.*)?)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /videos/%1/%4?id=%3 [NC,R=301]
```

I don't understand why it's not working.. Can someone help me ? Thanks !

Comment: ¿What's the fixed part in the URL you want to map. `_escaped_fragment_`, maybe? The mapping rule must be specific to an incoming URL pattern, ¿what's that pattern?

Comment: I want to redirect if the url contains the "_escaped_fragment_" parameter (for redirecting google ajax crawler). In my url only the four first params must be specified, the others can be set but they are optionnals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /videos/%1/%4/?id=%3&page=%2 [NC,R=301]
```